# Combining 2 similar fields into 1 in MS Access

Tags: sql, ms-access

I have 5 columns: c1=Item, c2=LHrs, c3=WHrs, c4=Lead, c5=Worker, constructed as such:

```
ITEM  LHRS  WHRS  LEAD  WORKER
123   25    10    John  Gary
456   15    20    John  John
```

I want results to appear like such:

```
RESOURCE  ITEM  HRS
John       123   25
Gary       123   10
John       456   35
```

Concatenate on the names and doing the results "AS Resource" doesn't break it down the way I want. Basically I want to know for each person, for each item, how many hours they are working wheter they are Lead (LHrs) or Worker (WHrs).

Thoughts?

Answer (score 3):

How about a UNION query?

```
SELECT item, person, sum(hrs) AS sumhours 
FROM (
   SELECT Item, lhrs as hrs,lead as person from wk
   UNION ALL
   SELECT Item, whrs, worker AS person from wk) a
GROUP BY item, person
```

Where wk is the name of the table.

Comment: Wouldn't that make item 456 to show up twice? Granted you could use a where clause to fix that. As Lhrs and whrs would needed to be added, and treated as such combined and not 2 separate entries.

Comment: No, it would not. 456 is two rows `John, lead, 15`, `John, worker, 20`, these are added to `John, 35`

Comment: @Halfwarr since its using standard sql its pretty [to test on sqlfiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/a214f/1)